# Finding possible or actual equation of cubic polynomial with a $y$ and an $x$ intercept

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Essentially given a graph that depicts a cubic function whose

1. Leading coefficient is positive,
2. $y$ intercept is $0,4$ and the only observable $x$ intercept is $-4,0$.

Without using math beyond algebra, how could you create a equation for a graph which is guaranteed to depict that behavior but might not be the exact same graph or find the actual equation of the graph.

Comment: Are you looking for a quadratic function (since those are generally trinomials, as in $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$)?

Comment: no  a trinomial is a polynomial with a degree of three as i understand it so actually four terms

Comment: @KiLlstealGaming You are wrong. A trinomial is a polynomial with 3 terms. For example, $x+y+1$ or $x^2y+xz+yz$. What you are looking for is a _cubic_ poylonomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are looking for a degree $3$ polynomial, which are often called cubic functions, I would proceed as follows:

I would take the most basic cubic function, $f(x)=x^3$ and think about how to transform it to meet the criteria you specified.

First I would translate it $4$ units to the left, which moves the $x$ intercept from $(0,0)$ to $(-4,0)$. Now the function is $f(x)=(x+4)^3$

Then I'd figure out the value of $a$ such that $f(x)=a\cdot(x+4)^3$ causes the function to have $y$ intercept at $(0,4)$

$a$ is the solution to $4=a\cdot(0+4)^3$. The solution is $a=\frac{1}{16}$.

So one function that meets your criteria is $f(x)=\frac{1}{16}\cdot(x+4)^3$, which you can expand to be $f(x)=\frac{1}{16}x^3+\frac34x^2+3x+4$

Answer (score 0):

If your function has real coefficients then there will be infinite such equations. @DreiCleaner has already found one solution but we can find the general form.

Since the function is cubic, $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx^2+d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are some real numbers.

Plugging in the solution $(x,y)=(0,4)$ we get $4=d$. So the equation is $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx^2+4$.

Now plugging in the solution $(-4,0)$ we get
$$0=-64a+16b-4c+4$$ Diving both sides by $-4$,
$$16a-4b+c+1=0$$

So the equation $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx^2+4$ will work for all $a,b,c$ such that $16a-4b+c=-1$. You can verify that even the equation in @DreiCleaner's solution satisfies this condition.